# ASP.NET MVC 3 IClientValidatable Attribute - Clear Parameters Cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation, validationattribute

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3. I have my added my own custom validation attribute:

```
public class CustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable {
    private readonly string _parameter1;

    public CustomAttribute(string parameter1) {
        _parameter1 = Global.Settings[parameter1];
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context) {
        ...
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule() { 
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName), 
            ValidationType = "custom", 
            ValidationParameters = { { "parameter1", _parameter1 } } 
        };
    }
}
```

Notice how it implements `IClientValidatable`. This renders the `parameters1` setting as a HTML 5 data attribute into the field on the page.

The problem i have is the value of the setting can change but every time it changes it still renders the old value inside the data attribute. I'm guessing this is cached somewhere. Is there anyway to remove the cache?

I'd appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a hack to solve this. You need to restart the application. This can be done programatically using HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain(). Incase your application is not in full trust mode then see http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Oct/08/Recycling-an-ASPNET-Application-from-within.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without restarting the application / pool? In a production environment this is an no go otherwise all active sessions are lost to say the least

Comment: Not as far as I can see. I haven't looked since I posted this question though, so maybe someone has come up with a better way.